# How to log hotspot login activity

Tags: hot-spot

I like many am having hotspot login related problems (where I can login using my Android phone but not with Ubuntu) but unlike anything that I've found, I just want to log the related messages. I've checked /var/log and I don't see the messages.

At the top of the Hotspot Login popup there is a string in very faint text that shows messages like:

http://pgcmlcp.pgcmls.local/guest/weblogin.php/7?_browser=1&cmd=login&mac=....&ip=10.191.14.191&essid=PGCMLS%20Public&apname=GR-2-3&apgroup=OurLocal%20Library&url=https%3A%2F%2Fyourdesiredwebpage%2Ecom%2F

and when the hotspot login fails I get a message in the hotspot login window proper:

error resolving "pgcmlcp.pgcmls.local"

It's failing, I guess, because it can't resolve the IP string, because the network isn't set up properly or something similar, but in any case, I'm not looking for help FIXING this problem, I just want to see what the wifi login procedure messages are. Without having to try to capture them and copy them off the hotspot login page.

thanks

ps why isn't there some simple little button in the Control or Networking GUI utility that enables and disables whatever blocks this from working when it works for Windows and Android? The relevant network administrators really do not care about this problem for one fringe OS. It's one less security headache for them. (should this be another question?)

Answer (score 0):

Manually setting your DNS servers could do the trick. You only need to figure out which one, but most likely on the gateway such as 192.168.1.1 or 10.0.0.1 etc.

Also the domain `.local` they are using for their hotspot could cause problems quick references [1](https://serverfault.com/questions/47087/using-local-for-internal-websites),[2](https://serverfault.com/questions/17255/top-level-domain-domain-suffix-for-private-network/17566#17566).